# Ask a question on compact set and distance function

Tags: analysis

Let A be a nonempty compact subset of $R$ (real numbers) and let B be a nonempty closed subset of R. Recall
that $\operatorname{dist}(A, B) = \inf{|x − y| : x ∈ A, y ∈ B}$. Show that there exist $a ∈ A$ and $b ∈ B$ such that
$|a − b| = \operatorname{dist}(A, B)$.

How to prove this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof: From the basic properties of the infimum, we know that we can find elements in a set that are arbitrarily close to its infimum. Then there exists a sequence $(|x_n-y_n|)$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} |x_n-y_n|= dis(A,B)$ where $x_n \in A$ and $y_n \in B$ for all n.

Because A is compact, $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$, where its limit is an element  $a \in A$ as a compact set is closed.

As every convergent sequence is bounded, we know that $(|x_n-y_n|)$ is bounded. Also, $\{x_n\}$ is obviously bounded because A is compact. From $|y_n| =|x_n-(x_n-y_n)| \leq |x_n|+|x_n-y_n|$, we see that $\{y_n\}$ is also bounded. In particular, $\{y_{n_k}\}$ is bounded. By Bolzano-Weirstrass Theorem, $\{y_{n_k}\}$ has a convergent subsequence: $y_{n_{k_l}} \to b$ as $l \to \infty$. Since B is closed, we have $b \in B$. We also have $x_{n_{k_l}} \to a \in A$ as $l \to \infty$.

Therefore, $dis(A,B)=\lim_{n\to \infty} |x_n-y_n|=\lim_{n\to \infty} |x_{n_{k_l}}-y_{n_{k_l}}| = |a-b|$, for the elements $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ found above.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the closed set $S = A - B$, which is $A + (-B)$, if it contains $0$, then $a = b$, and $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.
Otherwise, consider $s = dist(0,S)$, if $\pm s \in S$ then the statement is proven, this is a simpler version beacuse it is only one closed set and a point. You can take a look at this other question for a prove for that. [Distance to a closed set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83505/distance-to-a-closed-set)

Comment: I know how to prove A+B is closed. Is this useful?

Comment: Yes, $-B$ is just $B$ with the sign of the numbers flipped

Comment: okay, so now I know A-B is closed. Then what next?

Comment: Now the problem has turned into finding the distance between a closed set and a point, read the link I have posted for more information

Comment: I don't know why if $\pm s \in S$ then the statement is proven

Comment: $S$ has all the distances (with signs) between points from $A,B$, if the one closest to $0$ is in $S$ itself that means that there exist $a \in A,b \in B, a-b=s = dist(A,B)$, the other option would be to have a sequence approaching $s$, which means that there arent such $a,b$. This arises from the observation that $dist(0,S) = dist(A,B)$